# Spring Tool Suite - Project and External Dependencies - sort jars?

Tags: spring-tool-suite

Is there a way to sort the jars alphabetically? Currently, if i need to find a specific jar, i need to **manually** find the jar, by tapping its starting alphabet and keep tapping it to cycle through the list. It would be helpful if the jars were sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option to sort the library entries in the packages explorer alphabetically, if that is what you are looking for: `Preferences -> Java -> Appearance`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot Martin!